# Can Content-Disposition filename be used for text fields in multipart forms with Spring Webclient?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-headers, spring-webflux, content-disposition

Working with the Service-Now API (for example) requires the request to provide the following:

```
POST /api/now/attachment/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.testenv.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MadHyZrFTrZu0gW
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="table_name"

some_table

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="table_sys_id"

82c9aca7kljasdfkljhasdfec8dfdb61d961920

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="undefined"

Content-Type: file

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW—
```

The above is generated from using Postman and providing `form-data` key value pairs.

However, based off the abstract of the RFC that defines Content-Disposition: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183.

```
Two values for this
header field are described in this memo; one for the ordinary linear
presentation of the body part, and another to facilitate the use of
mail to transfer files.
```

The Content-Disposition class used in Spring Webflux (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html) contains only an internal field for "filename" that is a string.

Is the ContentDisposition class in org.springframework.http missing a component as per RFC-2183 regarding a standard value (ordinary linear presentation of the body part)?

The HTTP request that is generated by the spring code automagically is as follows:

```
POST /api/now/attachment/upload HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.9.RELEASE
transfer-encoding: chunked
host: somehost.testenv.com
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=o-0JsSvUdGo98NDHJSWTwjvgzlRSXsmJ98-pWQ;charset=UTF-8
```

This is the source code that generates the above HTTP request:

```java
MultipartBodyBuilder mbuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
mbuilder.part("table_name", snConfig.getChangeRecordTableName());
mbuilder.part("table_sys_id", result.get(0).getSysId());
mbuilder.part("uploadFile", someFile);

return client.post()
    .uri(snConfig.getEndpointAttachmentUpload())
    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    .syncBody(mbuilder.build())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(AttachmentUploadResult.class);
```

It looks like the code is storing all of the MultipartBodyBuilder components into a single multipart/form-data, which is not the same format as the working HTTP Request.

However, even by manually providing the Content-Disposition headers, one can only create a name/value pair where the value is the "filename".

Is Content-Disposition missing functionality? Is this possible with WebClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this isn't supported within WebClient after digging on this for a long while.